# How can I save additional fields upon user signup when using MEAN stack and Passport?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm trying to save more than just email and password when a user signs up on my site. All the Passport examples show only email and password being stored. What if I also have "gender", and "name" fields that need to be stored when a user signs up? I've spend all day trying to figure this out with no luck. Here is what I'm currently using:

passport.js:

```
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true
},
function(req, email, password, done) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
        User.findOne({ 'email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
            if (err)
                return done(err);
            if (user) {
                return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'Email is already taken.'));
            } else {
                var newUser = new User();
                newUser.email    = email;
                newUser.password = newUser.generateHash(password);
                newUser.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        throw err;
                    return done(null, newUser);
                });
            }
        });
    });
}));
```

routes.js:

```
app.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local-signup', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        if (!user) { return res.redirect('/'); }
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            // load up the user model
            var User = require('../app/models/user');
            var conditions = { email: req.user.email }
              , update = {
                    name: req.name, // works if I manually set "req.name" to "'Bill Smith'"
                    gender: req.gender // works if I manually set "req.gender" to "'Male'"
                         }
              , options = { multi: false };
            User.update(conditions, update, options, callback);
            function callback (err, numAffected) {
                // numAffected is the number of updated documents
            }
            return res.json({ response: 1, username: req.user.email });
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

angular.js:

```
$scope.signupMain = function () {
    var data = $.param({ 
        name: $('#name').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        password: $('#password').val(),
        gender: $('#gender').val()
    });
    $http({
        url: 'signup',
        method: "POST",
        data: data,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function (result, status, headers, config) { // Do something })
      .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { $scope.status = status; });
};
```

Everything works fine if I'm just trying to store the email and password when a users signs up, but all attempts at saving "name" and "gender" have failed. Basically, in `routes.js` I am unable to get `name: req.name` and `gender: req.gender` to work. That is, `req.name` and `req.gender` are not "getting" those values. It works if I manually enter values such as `name: 'Bill Smith'` and `gender: 'Male'`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post vars aren't going to be directly set on `req`.  They'd be on `req.body`, assuming you're using `bodyParser` or an equivalent middlware.  http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#req.body

Comment: I am using ``bodyParser`` and I tried ``gender: res.body.gender`` but the console gives an error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'gender' of undefined".

Comment: Mistake: I should have used ``gender: req.body.gender``. That works. Thanks for the info. I'm new to node. This helps me out a lot!

Comment: Np.  The express API page, while not exhaustive, explains a lot of the features pretty well.  It's always a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

1.- Add the new attributes to `passport.js`:

```
var newUser = new User();
newUser.email    = email;
newUser.password = newUser.generateHash(password);
newUser.gender   = req.body.gender; // Your new attribute (req.body = POST data)
newUser.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
        return done(null, newUser);
});
```

2.- Modify the **User** model and add the new attribute to the Schema

Comment: This is it, thanks Gilberto. FYI you don't need to update the first object you pass to new localStrategy (with usernameField, passwordField, etc.), just the part you where you create the new user (the code in Gilberto's comment).

Answer (score 1):

Use req.body to get the fields you need. You will need to parse it, however. You can use bodyParser for it.

Answer (score 0):

I  found this question while Googling, and req.body didn't work for me.  I had to use req.query.